# Maple (2023) ShowSolution does not compute the indeterminate limit infinity minus infinity in some cases

Tags: maple

In the following I show two functions `f` and `g` where `ShowSolution(Limit(..))` works for `f` but not for `g`. Any idea why?

```
with(Student[Calculus1]);

f := x^2 + x:
limit(f, x = -infinity);
infinity
ShowSolution(Limit(f, x = -infinity), maxsteps = 100);
// step-by-step solution is produced

g := x^2 + 3*x:
limit(g, x = -infinity);
infinity
ShowSolution(Limit(g, x = -infinity), maxsteps = 100);
Error, (in Student:-Calculus1:-ShowSolution) unable to compute solution steps
```

Maple is able to change `f` into an equivalent expression by factoring out `x^2`, but does not seem to be able to do it with `g`.

Comment: It is unable to find a corresponding helpful `rewrite` step, such as, say, `x^2+3*x = x^2*(1+3/x)` . It can get the solution, from there. I have submitted a bug report.